# Linux Process Scheduler

Tags: c, linux, process, scheduler

I am trying to write a process manager that schedules different processes using the real-time scheduling policy SCHED_FIFO. What I want to do is set the priorities of processes and have them execute according to the priority.

I have test processes that are paused, and wait to be resumed by the process manager so that they execute their tasks.

Here is part of the code for the test process:

```
while(1) {
  kill(myPid, SIGTSTP); // pause process until resumed by scheduler
  printf("Process %s with PID %d and priority %d\n",
  argv[0], myPid, param.sched_priority);
  printf("Process %s processing...\n", argv[0]);
  k = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) // do random task
  {
     for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
     {
        k++;
     }
  }
  printf("Process %s done.  Going to sleep.\n", argv[0]);
  sched_yield(); // yield the processor
}
```

The following is a sample code for the process manager:

```
pid_t child[3]; // holds child processes
while(1)
{

    for (i = 0; i < num_child; i++)
    {
       kill(child[i], SIGCONT); // resume process
       child_param.sched_priority = BASE_CHILD_PRIORITY + i * 10; // set priority
       sched_setscheduler(child[i], SCHED_FIFO, &child_param); // set policy
    }

}
```

Although I am able to get the highest priority to run first, the processes do not complete their task fully before yield the processor. The output of my problem can be seen below.

```
Process 1 with PID 5975 and priority 79
Process 1 processing...
Process 2 with PID 5974 and priority 69
Process 3 with PID 5973 and priority 59
Process 2 processing...
Process 3 processing...
Process 1 done.  Going to sleep.
Process 2 done.  Going to sleep.
Process 3 done.  Going to sleep.
```

Why don't the processes with SCHED_FIFO policy complete their full task before the next process starts?

Comment: Any chance this is running on a multi-core CPU?...

Comment: It is running on a single core computer

Comment: Output of `sysctl -a | grep sched_rt_` ?

Comment: kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000

kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000

Comment: That limits RT tasks to 95% of CPU time. It's a safety feature to avoid unintended hangups. Set `sched_rt_runtime_us` to -1 to disable it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCHED\_FIFO thread is preempted by SCHED\_OTHER thread in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287561/sched-fifo-thread-is-preempted-by-sched-other-thread-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

From the man page of [**`sched_setscheduler()`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html),

For processes scheduled under the `SCHED_FIFO` policy, the following rules apply :

1. A `SCHED_FIFO` process that has been preempted by another process of
     higher priority will stay at the head of the list for its priority
     and will resume execution as soon as all processes of higher
     priority are blocked again.
2. When a `SCHED_FIFO` process becomes runnable, it will be inserted at
     the end of the list for its priority.
3. A call to `sched_setscheduler()` or `sched_setparam()` will put the
     `SCHED_FIFO` process identified by pid at the start of
     the list if it was runnable.  As a consequence, it may preempt the
     currently running process if it has the same priority.
     (POSIX.1-2001 specifies that the process should go to the end of
     the list.)
4. A process calling `sched_yield()` will be put at the end of the
     list.

> **Rule1** and **Rule3** indirectly imply that `SCHED_FIFO` guarantees FIFO behaviour ONLY if another process of higher priority does NOT get
>   scheduled.

---

Further down the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html%29%20%3a),

> Processes scheduled under one of the real-time policies have a **`sched_priority`** value in the range 1(low) to 99(high).

The following line of code in your snippet

```
child_param.sched_priority = BASE_CHILD_PRIORITY + i * 10;
```

sets higher priorities to the latter processes. Thus they tend to preempt the earlier processes.

<sub>**Note** : POSIX.1-2001 requires an implementation to support only a minimum 32 distinct priority levels for the real-time policies, and some systems supply just this minimum.  Portable programs should use `sched_get_priority_min()` and `sched_get_priority_max()` to find the range of priorities supported for a particular policy.</sub>

Comment: The latter processes seem to be preempted as well. If you have a look at the output, none of the processes fully complete their task.

Comment: Can you try by calling `sched_setscheduler()` **before** resuming the process with `SIGCONT`?

Comment: I tried it. It gives me the same result. Is it possible that there other processes that preempt my test processes?

Comment: Only thing left now are the calls to `printf()` which can potentially allow the scheduler a point where it chooses to preempt the process that is stalled on the `printf()` call. You could try to modify all but the final `printf()` to be without a `\n` so that all the intermediate ones are buffered. However [`printf()` in realtime processes is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17910755/319204).